# Unable to connect to git remote repository

Tags: git, github

After performing `git push -u origin master`, I got:

```sh
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/xxxx/xxxx.git': Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1 port 8087: Connection refused
```

Same error occurred, when I tried to clone other repositories, too.

The Port 8087 doesn't seem to be busy. What could go wrong?

**Edit:**
when I do clone from `git://` instead of `https://`, it works just fine.

Comment: Laurent and Liao’ answers really help. For your information, the .gitconfig file usually locate at the root folder of your user name, e.g., C:\Users\Zengxiaoyu

Answer (score 82):

This happens because a proxy is configured in git.

Since it's https proxy (and not http) `git config http.proxy` and `git config --global http.proxy` can't help.

1. Take a look at your git configuration

   ```
   git config --global -l
   ```

   If you have nothing related to https proxy like `https_proxy=...` the problem is not here.

   If you have something related to https proxy then remove it from the file `~/.gitconfig` and try again
2. If it still doesn't work, unset environment variables

   Check your environment variables :

   ```
   env|grep -i proxy
   ```

   You should have one or several lines with `https_proxy=...`

   Unset one by one with :
   `unset https_proxy` (or HTTPS_PROXY depending of the name of the variable)
3. Check environment variables again

   ```
   env|grep -i proxy
   ```

   If it shows nothing you should be good.

   Note: This solution can applies to http and https proxy problems. just the variables name changes from https to http

Comment: I used Fiddler recently on ubuntu and it has added all HTTP, HTTPS and FTP proxies making my life harder. Due to that git pull fails with a connection error on port 8888. After following this and deleting those environment variables, I was able to solve my issue. You saved my day! Really appreciate this. Thanks !

Comment: If we are not using SSH then don't need the proxy setting, It fixed for me I just removed the proxy from git config. Thanks. @Laurent

Answer (score 21):

`git config --global --unset http.proxy`

Answer (score 7):

Laurent's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43137514/1283715) worked for me. (I am behind corporate firewall.)
In my case,

- I removed the proxy setting in `.gitconfig` file.
- Everything just work fine. I can clone from a remote repo.
- When i wanted to push to the remote repo, I generated a `ssh key`. Then I am able to push.

**Hope it saves someones 2 hours.**

Answer (score 3):

It seems that git tries to use a local proxy.

Please check your global network-settings and those of git.

Use `git config http.proxy` and `git config --global http.proxy` to get the proxy-settings of git.

Answer (score 1):

I had tried all the methods mentioned above, but I was missing something other than what they have mentioned,

**try to update your credentials in Control panel -> User Accounts -> Credential Manager for Git** it worked for me