# Unable to execute mojo: Command execution failed. Process exited with an error: 3 when using maven grunt plugin on Angular 2 typescript

Tags: maven, typescript, gruntjs, angular

My goal is to set up a maven springboot project with Typescript Angular 2 framework. Eventually after I hit command ("mvn install"), corresponding js files will get compiled from the ts files.

This is the error I get after hitting that command.

```
[INFO] Compiling 2 source files to C:\workspace_angular\springbootAngular2\target\classes
[INFO]
[INFO] --- grunt-maven-plugin:1.0.2:grunt (compile) @ springbootAngular2 ---
[INFO] OS Name: Windows 10
Running "typescript:compile" (typescript) task
The 'base_path' option will be obsoleted. Please use the 'basePath'.
>> C:/workspace_angular/springbootAngular2/src/main/ts/app.component.ts(1,1):
>> error TS1008: Unexpected token; 'module, class, interface, enum, import or statement' expected.
>> C:/workspace_angular/springbootAngular2/src/main/ts/app.component.ts(1,25):
>> error TS1005: ';' expected.
>> C:/workspace_angular/springbootAngular2/src/main/ts/app.component.ts(2,1):
>> error TS1001: Unexpected character "@".
>> C:/workspace_angular/springbootAngular2/src/main/ts/app.component.ts(2,1):
>> error TS1008: Unexpected token; 'module, class, interface, enum, import or statement' expected.
Warning: Task "typescript:compile" failed. Use --force to continue.

Aborted due to warnings.
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 03:01 min
[INFO] Finished at: 2016-04-24T13:32:09-04:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 29M/441M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal pl.allegro:grunt-maven-plugin:1.0.2:grunt (compile) on project springbootAngular2: Unable to execute mojo: Command execution failed. Process exited with an error: 3 (Exit value: 3) -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal pl.allegro:grunt-maven-plugin:1.0.2:grunt (compile) on project springbootAngular2: Unable to execute mojo
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:212)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:116)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:80)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:307)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:193)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:106)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:863)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:288)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:199)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: Unable to execute mojo
        at org.twdata.maven.mojoexecutor.MojoExecutor.executeMojo(MojoExecutor.java:96)
        at pl.allegro.tdr.gruntmaven.AbstractExecutableMojo.execute(AbstractExecutableMojo.java:77)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:134)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:207)
        ... 20 more
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: Command execution failed.
        at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecMojo.execute(ExecMojo.java:362)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:134)
        at org.twdata.maven.mojoexecutor.MojoExecutor.executeMojo(MojoExecutor.java:94)
        ... 23 more
Caused by: org.apache.commons.exec.ExecuteException: Process exited with an error: 3 (Exit value: 3)
        at org.apache.commons.exec.DefaultExecutor.executeInternal(DefaultExecutor.java:377)
        at org.apache.commons.exec.DefaultExecutor.execute(DefaultExecutor.java:160)
        at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecMojo.executeCommandLine(ExecMojo.java:610)
        at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecMojo.execute(ExecMojo.java:352)
        ... 25 more
[ERROR]
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

I have 2 simple ts files to compile. I believe the ts codes are correct since they runs in the "npm way".

And I will continue to share my configuration related to the matter.

**springbootAngular2/package.json**

```
{
  "name": "springbootAngular2",
  "version": "0.0.1-SNAPSHOT",
  "devDependencies": {
    "concurrently": "^2.0.0",
    "lite-server": "^2.2.0",
    "typescript": "^1.8.10",
    "typings":"^0.7.12"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "grunt": "~0.4.1",
    "grunt-typescript": "~0.2.4",
    "grunt-contrib-clean": "~0.5.0",
    "grunt-contrib-jasmine": "~0.5.2",
    "grunt-contrib-yuidoc": "~0.5.0",
    "grunt-template-jasmine-istanbul": "~0.2.5",
    "grunt-template-jasmine-requirejs": "~0.1.7",
    "grunt-contrib-uglify": "~0.2.5",
    "angular2": "2.0.0-beta.15",
    "systemjs": "0.19.26",
    "es6-shim": "^0.35.0",
    "reflect-metadata": "0.1.2",
    "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.2",
    "zone.js": "0.6.10"
  }
}
```

**springbootAngular2/tsconfig.json**

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "system",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "removeComments": false,
    "noImplicitAny": false
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "typings/main",
    "typings/main.d.ts"
  ]
}
```

**springbootAngular2/typings.json**

```
{
  "ambientDependencies": {
    "es6-shim": "github:DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/es6-shim/es6-shim.d.ts#7de6c3dd94feaeb21f20054b9f30d5dabc5efabd",
    "jasmine": "github:DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/jasmine/jasmine.d.ts#7de6c3dd94feaeb21f20054b9f30d5dabc5efabd"
  }
}
```

**springbootAngular2/Gruntfile.js**  (code fragment for dir definition and typescript:compile part)

```
// define some directories to be used during build
dir: {

    // location of all source files
    "source": "src",

    // location where TypeScript source files are located
    "source_ts": "src/main/ts",
    // location where TypeScript/Jasmine test files are located
    "source_test_ts": "src/test/ts",

    // location where all build files shall be placed
    "target": "target",

    // location to place (compiled) javascript files
    //Chrystian note: target file directory is changed
    "target_js": "target/js",
    //"target_js" : "src/main/resources/public/app",
    // location to place (compiles) javascript test files
    "target_test_js": "target/js-test",
    // location to place documentation, etc.
    "target_report": "target/report"
},
typescript: {

    // Compiles main code. Add declaration file files
    compile: {
        src: ['<%= dir.source_ts %>/**/*.ts'],
        dest: '<%= dir.target_js %>',
        options: {
            base_path: '<%= dir.source_ts %>',
            target: 'es5',
            declaration: true,
            comments: true,
            module: 'amd'
        }
    },

    // Compiles the tests (and the module code again so that import paths are working).
    compile_test: {
        src: ['<%= dir.source_test_ts %>/**/*.ts','<%= dir.source_ts %>/**/*.ts'],
        dest: '<%= dir.target_test_js %>',
        options: {
            base_path: '<%= dir.source %>',
            target: 'es5',
            module: 'amd'
        }
    }
},
```

and the grunt plugin defined in the **pom.xml**

```
            <plugin>
                <groupId>pl.allegro</groupId>
                <artifactId>grunt-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.0.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <gruntBuildDirectory>${project.build.directory}/grunt</gruntBuildDirectory>
                </configuration>
                <executions>

                    <!--
                       Maven "validate" phase: Prepare everything that is required to run grunt
                    -->
                    <execution>
                        <id>validate</id>
                        <phase>validate</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <!--<goal>create-resources</goal>-->
                            <goal>npm</goal><!-- setup grunt and plugin -->
                        </goals>
                    </execution>

                    <!--
                       Maven "compile" phase: Do the real stuff by running grunt with target "compile"
                    -->
                    <execution>
                        <id>compile</id>
                        <phase>compile</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>grunt</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <target>compile</target>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
.
.
```

In addition, the folder **typings** did not get generated as it would under the "npm way".

Hope the information is sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

For me, the issue occured because i was connected with vpn network and by default https_proxy were enabled.

After running the below command and executing mvn has resolved the problem.

```
>unset https_proxy
>unset http_proxy
>unset ftp_proxy
>mvn clean install
```

Follow the 2nd method of below link for more info:
[git cannot clone or push? failed to connect, connection refused](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24543372/git-cannot-clone-or-push-failed-to-connect-connection-refused)

This configuration gets enabled again, once you close the terminal.